# Macro for Essbase data retrieval

Tags: vba, excel, automation, essbase

I am ultimately trying to automate/schedule a data retrieval from Essbase.

I started with a macro that works perfectly. Sample code:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
range("B1:b1").Select
ActiveCell = j
application.Run macro:="EssMenuVRetrieve"
```

This macro will run in about 0.5 seconds and retrieves the data perfectly.

Next I wrote a .bat and vbScript file to automate the process. but this will not work.

**Everything runs fine up until the EssMenuVRetrieve line of code.** I know this because I put in sample code before and after to write some text to two cells for testing purposes.

When I run the batch file, it calls the macro as I want, executes the code upto EssMenueVRetrieve and then just hangs infinitely. No data comes back. And no code after it gets executed.

**I cannot understand the issue going from a working macro to a not working vbscript.**

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had much luck using EssMenuVRetrieve method.  Take a look at the "library" of functions that come with the Essbase addin.  It should be under the ExcelAddin -> bin foler and is called "essxlvba.txt" (or something like that).  I read through that and successfully came up with a solution similar to the one below.  It works perfectly with a scheduled bat script that opens about 15 different files and performs 100+ retrieves.

```
Dim wsTar as Worksheet
    Set wsTar = thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1")
Dim rngTar as Range
    Set rngTar = wsTar.Range("B1:B1")
'EssVConnect...
EssVRetrieve wsTar, rngTar, 1 'this is the line that performs the actual retrieve
'EssVDisconnect
```